# Is it possible to scope url(#id) attributes with SVG elements in a web page?

Tags: dom, svg

In SVG, you can use a URL reference, such as `url(#id)`, to point to other SVG elements on a web page. For example:

```
<use filter="url(#my-filter)" ...></use>
```

But suppose that, by accident, I end up with a naming collision like this:

```
<svg>
  <defs>
    <filter id="my-filter" x="30">
  </defs>
  <use filter="url(#my-filter)"></use>
</svg>

<!-- somewhere else on my page --->
<svg>
  <defs>
    <filter id="my-filter" x="40">
  </defs>
  <use filter="url(#my-filter)"></use>
</svg>
```

Unfortunately it seems that these `url()` references are not scoped. When this page displays, both of them will use the same filter -- presumably the first  element to match the selector `#my-filter` (as opposed to the `<filter>` located within the `<svg>` context of each).

Is there some way to add scoping so that each reference points to the intended place? Or do I just have to make sure that these ids are always globally unique on my web page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, id values must be [unique on a page](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute).

> The (id) value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain any space characters.