# SVG turns into a black box if another instance is hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have two divs each containing an instances of the same svg.

When I set the first div to "display: none", the svg in the second div turns into a grey box.

This is happening in both firefox and chrome.

Why is this happening and what can I do to get around it?

Here's some sample code:

P.S. I was given the svg by our designer.

**(EDIT: I'm on Chrome Version 64.0.3282.167 and Firefox 45.9.0. Also, In the actual project. I'm importing the SVG as a React Component. So any change to the SVG will appear in both instances)**

```js
$("#button").click(function(){
  $("#firstDiv").css("display","none");
})

$("#button2").click(function(){
  $("#firstDiv").css("display","inherit");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script> 

<button id="button">Hide First Div</button>
<button id="button2">Show First Div</button>
<div id="firstDiv">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg height="100" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 20 20" style="enable-background:new 0 0 20 20;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
 .st0{filter:url(#Adobe_OpacityMaskFilter);}
 .st1{fill:#FFFFFF;}
 .st2{mask:url(#mask-2_1_);}
 .st3{fill:#666666;}
</style>
<title>Icon/Close Copy</title>
<desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
<g id="Cross" transform="translate(-1397.000000, -1518.000000)">
 <g id="Group-44" transform="translate(0.000000, 1495.000000)">
  <g id="Icon_x2F_Close" transform="translate(1391.000000, 17.000000)">
   <g id="Combined-Shape" transform="translate(16.000000, 16.000000) rotate(-315.000000) translate(-16.000000, -16.000000) ">
   </g>
   <defs>
    <filter id="Adobe_OpacityMaskFilter" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="-6.6" y="-6.6" width="45.3" height="45.3">
     <feColorMatrix  type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 1 0"/>
    </filter>
   </defs>
   <mask maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="-6.6" y="-6.6" width="45.3" height="45.3" id="mask-2_1_">
    <g class="st0">
     <path id="path-1_1_" class="st1" d="M16,14.6l7.8-7.8l1.4,1.4L17.4,16l7.8,7.8l-1.4,1.4L16,17.4l-7.8,7.8l-1.4-1.4l7.8-7.8
      L6.8,8.2l1.4-1.4L16,14.6z"/>
    </g>
   </mask>
   <g id="Color_x2F_Dark-Grey" class="st2">
    
     <rect id="Rectangle-2" x="0" y="0" transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -6.6274 16)" class="st3" width="32" height="32"/>
   </g>
  </g>
 </g>
</g>
</svg>
</div>
  <div>
<svg height="100" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 20 20" style="enable-background:new 0 0 20 20;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
 .st0{filter:url(#Adobe_OpacityMaskFilter);}
 .st1{fill:#FFFFFF;}
 .st2{mask:url(#mask-2_1_);}
 .st3{fill:#666666;}
</style>
<title>Icon/Close Copy</title>
<desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
<g id="Cross" transform="translate(-1397.000000, -1518.000000)">
 <g id="Group-44" transform="translate(0.000000, 1495.000000)">
  <g id="Icon_x2F_Close" transform="translate(1391.000000, 17.000000)">
   <g id="Combined-Shape" transform="translate(16.000000, 16.000000) rotate(-315.000000) translate(-16.000000, -16.000000) ">
   </g>
   <defs>
    <filter id="Adobe_OpacityMaskFilter" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="-6.6" y="-6.6" width="45.3" height="45.3">
     <feColorMatrix  type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 1 0"/>
    </filter>
   </defs>
   <mask maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="-6.6" y="-6.6" width="45.3" height="45.3" id="mask-2_1_">
    <g class="st0">
     <path id="path-1_1_" class="st1" d="M16,14.6l7.8-7.8l1.4,1.4L17.4,16l7.8,7.8l-1.4,1.4L16,17.4l-7.8,7.8l-1.4-1.4l7.8-7.8
      L6.8,8.2l1.4-1.4L16,14.6z"/>
    </g>
   </mask>
   <g id="Color_x2F_Dark-Grey" class="st2">
    
     <rect id="Rectangle-2" x="0" y="0" transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -6.6274 16)" class="st3" width="32" height="32"/>
   </g>
  </g>
 </g>
</g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you use so complex `svg`s? What are they for?

Comment: @KoshVery This is just the svg given to me by the designer. I was actually also wondering if there are tools to simplify these SVGs, or if there are certain settings I should tell my designers to use when they export SVGs.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45536618/is-it-possible-to-scope-urlid-attributes-with-svg-elements-in-a-web-page/45540406#45540406

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have several elements (even within `svg` containers) with the same `id`. `id` should be unique.

See the snippet:

```js
$("#button").click(function(){
  $("#firstDiv").css("display","none");
})

$("#button2").click(function(){
  $("#firstDiv").css("display","block");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script> 

<button id="button">Hide First Div</button>
<button id="button2">Show First Div</button>
<div id="firstDiv">

<svg height="100" version="1.1" id="Layer_0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 20 20" style="enable-background:new 0 0 20 20;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
 .st0{filter:url(#Adobe_OpacityMaskFilter0);}
 .st1{fill:#FFFFFF;}
 .st2{mask:url(#mask-2_1_1);}
 .st3{fill:#666666;}
</style>
<title>Icon/Close Copy</title>
<desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
<g id="Cross" transform="translate(-1397.000000, -1518.000000)">
 <g id="Group-44" transform="translate(0.000000, 1495.000000)">
  <g id="Icon_x2F_Close" transform="translate(1391.000000, 17.000000)">
   <g id="Combined-Shape" transform="translate(16.000000, 16.000000) rotate(-315.000000) translate(-16.000000, -16.000000) ">
   </g>
   <defs>
    <filter id="Adobe_OpacityMaskFilter0" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="-6.6" y="-6.6" width="45.3" height="45.3">
     <feColorMatrix  type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 1 0"/>
    </filter>
   </defs>
   <mask maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="-6.6" y="-6.6" width="45.3" height="45.3" id="mask-2_1_1">
    <g class="st0">
     <path id="path-1_1_" class="st1" d="M16,14.6l7.8-7.8l1.4,1.4L17.4,16l7.8,7.8l-1.4,1.4L16,17.4l-7.8,7.8l-1.4-1.4l7.8-7.8
      L6.8,8.2l1.4-1.4L16,14.6z"/>
    </g>
   </mask>
   <g id="Color_x2F_Dark-Grey" class="st2">
    
     <rect id="Rectangle-2" x="0" y="0" transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -6.6274 16)" class="st3" width="32" height="32"/>
   </g>
  </g>
 </g>
</g>
</svg>
</div>

<div>
<svg height="100" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 20 20" sstyle="enable-background:new 0 0 20 20;" xxml:sspace="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
 .st0{filter:url(#Adobe_OpacityMaskFilter);}
 .st1{fill:#FFFFFF;}
 .st2{mask:url(#mask-2_1_);}
 .st3{fill:#666666;}
</style>
<title>Icon/Close Copy</title>
<desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
<g id="Cross" transform="translate(-1397.000000, -1518.000000)">
 <g id="Group-44" transform="translate(0.000000, 1495.000000)">
  <g id="Icon_x2F_Close" transform="translate(1391.000000, 17.000000)">
   <g id="Combined-Shape" transform="translate(16.000000, 16.000000) rotate(-315.000000) translate(-16.000000, -16.000000) ">
   </g>
   <defs>
    <filter id="Adobe_OpacityMaskFilter" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="-6.6" y="-6.6" width="45.3" height="45.3">
     <feColorMatrix  type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 1 0"/>
    </filter>
   </defs>
   <mask maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="-6.6" y="-6.6" width="45.3" height="45.3" id="mask-2_1_">
    <g class="st0">
     <path id="path-1_1_" class="st1" d="M16,14.6l7.8-7.8l1.4,1.4L17.4,16l7.8,7.8l-1.4,1.4L16,17.4l-7.8,7.8l-1.4-1.4l7.8-7.8
      L6.8,8.2l1.4-1.4L16,14.6z"/>
    </g>
   </mask>
   <g id="Color_x2F_Dark-Grey" class="st2">
    
     <rect id="Rectangle-2" x="0" y="0" transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -6.6274 16)" class="st3" width="32" height="32"/>
   </g>
  </g>
 </g>
</g>
</svg>
</div>
```

If it's used as a 'delete' icon, your `svg` is overcomplicated. There should not be any masks, groups, styles, defs etc. It should be like this:

```css
svg {width:50px; fill:#777}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 96 96"><path d="M96 14L82 0 48 34 14 0 0 14l34 34L0 82l14 14 34-34 34 34 14-14-34-34z"/></svg>
```

Comment: That works. But is there a way for this to work while both SVGs are identical? The reason I ask is, the same SVG is being referenced by multiple components throughout the project. Or are there ways to configure unique ids within the svg across all the different instances? This is a React application btw.

Comment: It depends on what the `svg`s are used for. Please elaborate.

Comment: It's used as a 'delete' icon. We have something similar to a to-do list. There's a list of text with crosses next to it. Clicking on the cross will remove the respective item. New items can be added too.

Comment: For SVG embedded within a HTML page namespace (xmlns) definitions are not required either

Comment: @RobertLongson, thanks, I've copied it from a file. Removed.

Comment: I am having a similar issue. The problem is how can I convert the SVG to on that does not use mask

Comment: @Chidiebere, please try to search it on stackoverflow and google, and feel free to ask a separate question if results are not satisfying =))

Comment: I was able to solve my issue by adding a mask id to all my icons programmatically. I did not like that solution though but that worked fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to repeat the cross SVG in every `<div>`.  You can tidy the page (and reduce its size) by including the Cross SVG once and referencing it in each div with a `<use>` element.

```js
$("#button").click(function(){
  $("#firstDiv").css("display","none");
})

$("#button2").click(function(){
  $("#firstDiv").css("display","block");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script> 


<button id="button">Hide First Div</button>
<button id="button2">Show First Div</button>
<div id="firstDiv">
  <svg width="100" height="100" id="close" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
    <use xlink:href="#Cross"/>
  </svg>
</div>

<div>
  <svg width="100" height="100" id="close" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
    <use xlink:href="#Cross"/>
  </svg>
</div>


<!-- hide the referenced SVG on the page by setting its width and height to 0 -->
<svg width="0" height="0" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
<style type="text/css">
 .st1{fill:#FFFFFF;}
 .st2{mask:url(#mask-2_1_1);}
 .st3{fill:#666666;}
</style>
<g id="Cross" transform="translate(-1397.000000, -1518.000000)">
 <g id="Group-44" transform="translate(0.000000, 1495.000000)">
  <g id="Icon_x2F_Close" transform="translate(1391.000000, 17.000000)">
   <g id="Combined-Shape" transform="translate(16.000000, 16.000000) rotate(-315.000000) translate(-16.000000, -16.000000) ">
   </g>
   <mask maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="-6.6" y="-6.6" width="45.3" height="45.3" id="mask-2_1_1">
    <g class="st0">
     <path id="path-1_1_" class="st1" d="M16,14.6l7.8-7.8l1.4,1.4L17.4,16l7.8,7.8l-1.4,1.4L16,17.4l-7.8,7.8l-1.4-1.4l7.8-7.8
      L6.8,8.2l1.4-1.4L16,14.6z"/>
    </g>
   </mask>
   <g id="Color_x2F_Dark-Grey" class="st2">
     <rect id="Rectangle-2" x="0" y="0" transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -6.6274 16)" class="st3" width="32" height="32"/>
   </g>
  </g>
 </g>
</g>
</svg>
```